# How to filter data from JS array and create another JS array

Tags: javascript

I want to filter data from the JS array and create another JS array. I explained the scenario as below.

There are two JS arrays. they are `arr1` and `arr2`

```
const arr1 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}];
```

```
const arr2 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}, 
{
  code: "vvg",
  dis: "cont15",
  note: "Note for cont15"
}];
```

we can do change in `arr2[1].dis` and `arr2[2].note` and `arr2[4].note`. I have mentioned it in below

```
const arr2 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2 new",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "New Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}, 
{
  code: "VVG",
  dis: "cont15",
  note: "Note for cont15 changed"
}];
```

Once I changed the `arr2` I want to compare it with `arr1` and create `new_arr` and push all the changed elements to the `new_arr`. Compare should be done with `code`. Because `code: "VVG"` has a change. But it should not be contained a new array. Because `code: "VVG"` not in `arr1`.

```
Expected-output :

[
  {
    code: "AAW",
    dis: "cont2 new",
    note: "Note for cont2"
  },
  {
    code: "TTR",
    dis: "cont5",
    note: "New Note for cont5"
  }
]
```

Tried code:

```
const codesss = new Set(arr1.map(({ code }) => code));
const  new_arr = arr2.filter(({ code }) => !codesss.has(code));

console.log(new_arr);
```

current output:

```
[
  {
    "code": "VVG",
    "dis": "cont15",
    "note": "Note for cont15 changed"
  }
]
```

My `current output` is not the `Expected-output`. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, using `Array.prototype.reduce`, you can build new object from `arr1` with the `code` variable as `key`.

Based on that object, you can filter the objects needed using `Array.prototype.filter`.

```js
const arr1 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}];

const arr2 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2 new",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "New Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}, 
{
  code: "VVG",
  dis: "cont15",
  note: "Note for cont15 changed"
}];

const arr1Obj = arr1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.code] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = arr2.filter((item) => arr1Obj[item.code] && !(arr1Obj[item.code].dis === item.dis && arr1Obj[item.code].note === item.note));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr1 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}];

const arr2 = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}, 
{
  code: "vvg",
  dis: "cont15",
  note: "Note for cont15"
}];

const arr2Changed = [
{
  code: "XXY",
  dis: "cont1",
  note: "Note for cont1"
}, 
{
  code: "AAW",
  dis: "cont2 new",
  note: "Note for cont2"
}, 
{
  code: "TTR",
  dis: "cont5",
  note: "New Note for cont5"
}, 
{
  code: "MMN",
  dis: "cont10",
  note: "Note for cont10"
}, 
{
  code: "VVG",
  dis: "cont15",
  note: "Note for cont15 changed"
}];

const arr1Codes = {};
const newArray = [];
arr1.map(i => arr1Codes[i.code] = 1);
arr2Changed.map((item, index) => {
  const arr2Item = arr2[index];
  if (arr1Codes[arr2Item.code] && (arr2Item.dis !== item.dis || arr2Item.note !== item.note)) {
    newArray.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```